# Objective C: Access Variable From View Controller To NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsobject

I am started learning objective c again, and I am trying to access a variable from my main view controller in my NSObject class.

How would I do that?

For example I have declared

UITextField *name;

and I want to use it in my NSObject.

Comment: you have this declared as property or as class variable?

Comment: @ReinierMelian I have declared it as property, here, with (readwrite, nonatomic)

Comment: I do not understand quite well your question you are trying to access to your variable?

Comment: @ReinierMelian I have declared the variable in my ViewController.h and then I want to use that variable in an NSObject so I can change its value.

Comment: What is the relationship between the view controller and the object that wants to update it?  (Actually, this whole thing sounds backwards.  Normally, the controller should update its own properties by requesting information from a data model, not by having new data pushed to it.)

Answer (score 0):

The best practise would be implement delegate pattern here. Suppose you want to change the value/content of UITextField, then fire the delegate with the value. And in ViewController class, set the delegate and implement that delegate method. In that delegate method, update value/content of UITextField.

One more thing, Please make sure to update UITextField's content/value in main thread. UI related changes should be always done in main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the NSObject class via a method with the plus sign '+' `+(type)anyMethod;` to get the variable. If I correctly understood what you mean